# How does Map handles index collision?

Tags: dictionary, haxe, hash-collision, openfl

I'm trying to create a collection that maps a certain Type to my Vector2i type in this fashion:

```
Collection<Vector2i, Type>
```

I'm translating a project I had previously in C# to Haxe. In C# I only had to implement an interface in Vector2i to be able to index Dictionary using Vector2i, but I'm not sure what I have to do to achieve the same with Haxe.

Comment: A simple Map<Interface, SomType> should work ... are you having issues with that?

Comment: "Interface" is just a placeholder for whatever object type you want to use.